How to use Symbolic Regression to approximate Pascal's triangle?
I have been trying out symbolic regression and was wondering how to use it approximate a row of Pascal's triangle for example.  I make the data with:
import math
 
def print_pascals_triangle_row(n):
    row = []
    for k in range(n + 1):
       coefficient = math.comb(n, k)
       row.append(coefficient)
    return row
 
n = 20
pascals_triangle_row = print_pascals_triangle_row(n)

This gives:
[1,
 20,
 190,
 1140,
 4845,
 15504,
 38760,
 77520,
 125970,
 167960,
 184756,
 167960,
 125970,
 77520,
 38760,
 15504,
 4845,
 1140,
 190,
 20,
 1]

y = pascals_triangle_row
X = np.array(range(len(y))).reshape(-1, 1)

Set up the model:
from pysr import PySRRegressor
model = PySRRegressor(
    maxsize=15,
    niterations=5000,  # < Increase me for better results
    binary_operators=["+", "*"],
    unary_operators=[
        "log",
        "exp",
         "inv",
         "square",
        "sqrt",
        "sign",
        # ^ Custom operator (julia syntax)
    ],
    # ^ Define operator for SymPy as well
    elementwise_loss="loss(prediction, target) = (prediction - target)^2",
    # ^ Custom loss function (julia syntax)
)

And finally fit the model:
model.fit(X, y)

This doesn't give a model that is anywhere near accurate. My guess is the fundamental reason is that it can't do x**x which is need to approximate factorial.
Is there any way to allow symbolic regression to use the binary operator ** or otherwise fit a row of Pascal's triangle?

Have you tried pow? It is supposed to be that simple.

That being said, you already have exp and log. So, sure, it uses 2 level instead of one, but regression is free to use exp(x*log(x)). And I've played with pysr to try your example. I find it already pretty decent. Maybe your are expecting too much from it. The error is (even without pow under 0.3% (for the middle values. For small values it is bigger, in %, but that's the problem of this loss function: it doesn't know that 184856 instead of 184756 is a pretty good approximation when 101 instead of 1 is a bad one). Maybe you should use another loss function if that is the problem

@chrslg what is the best formula you get?

Without pow: y = (-383.43 + exp(((-20.001 + x₀) * (x₀ * -0.097014)) + 2.4288)) * sign(x₀)

With pow: y = ((0.35995 + square(-0.90689 ^ square(x₀))) ^ (1.1662 ^ x₀)) * (x₀ ^ 7.3298) (which is less good. Probably because the search space is bigger, so less solutions are explored in those 5000 iterations. Or simply because of luck. I don't know how that regression algorithm works, if there is some luck involved, nor what they call "iteration". But if it were an comprehensive search among all possible combination, one would expect that with pow you get a better result, or, at least the same, since the algorithm still have the option not to use pow)

And without pow and with another loss function (loss(prediction, target) = (prediction/target - 1)^2): y = square(square(square(square(square((x₀ + -10) * -0.11105) + -2.0443) + 0.34588)))

That first formula means that predicted y are [0, -311, -9, 1215, 5259, 16022, 38902, 77100, 125486, 168025, 185202, 168061, 125540, 77150, 38936, 16040, 5267, 1217, -9, -311, -371]. Which seems BS looking at the first values. But from the point of view of the loss function, that means a maximum difference of 536. Which is not a lot compared to the 184756 we find in y.  (it is a lot compared to smaller values, sure. But that loss function doesn't really care)

The last formula (with the loss function that cares about proportional error, rather than absolute error), yields to [1, 18, 185, 1175, 5100, 16229, 39716, 77328, 122614, 160762, 175791, 160762, 122614, 77328, 39716, 16229, 5100, 1175, 185, 18, 1]

Which is nicer to see, compared to real target values ([1, 20, 190, 1140, 4845, 15504, 38760, 77520, 125970, 167960, 184756, 167960, 125970, 77520, 38760, 15504, 4845, 1140, 190, 20, 1]). But that means that maximum error is now 9000 instead of 536. almost 20 times more. But in % it never goes over 10% (even for smaller values — those 18 vs 20), when the 1st formula have some 3700% error on smaller values.

How did you include pow?  If I add it to the list I get "JuliaError: The operator pow is not well-defined over the real line"

Just binary_operators=["+", "*", "pow"]. I get a warning that I should add constraints, but it works. And, indeed, the result, without constraints, as the warning says, is more complex than what I had in mind, because there is some a ^ (b ^ (c ^ bla)), with arbitrary complex expression as second argument of pow, when one would expect exponent to be either a constant, or, just a variable, like in x^x. So I have a warning about that. But nothing more, and it works.

@chrslg Thanks. pow isn't listed at https://astroautomata.com/PySR/operators/ so it's interesting that it works. I think you should be able to define a unary operator x**x but I haven't got that to work.

I found it there. But I guess that plus is synonym of +, mult of *,... and pow of ^. So '^' would probably have worked too. Just, in binary_operators, not in unary_operator where your code shows a commented ^.  And incidently, that documentation contains also a section about custom operators. That you could use indeed to define a unary selfpow(x) = x>0 ? x^x : 0  or something of that nature. But don't expect much of it: stirling approximation for comb(20,10) is 2323 off the exact value, which is not as my 536 without pow

@chrslg maybe you can define a unary factorial function?

Sure. Or a binary comb function while at it:D (I don't know what your are trying to do. Me, I am playing with your question because I find fun to discover that symbolic regression package I didn't knew about before. So I can't help thinking "but that is cheating". But maybe you have a real need, for which giving it a binary comb operator isn't cheating :))

Btw, yes, if I use factorial as one of the unary function, it did end up on expected formula. To be more accurate, if I use gamma. Because, there are probably some local derivative involved in the regression. When I use factorial, it chooses not to use it at all (or, sometimes, during the iterations, in totally unrelated usages, like sqrt(gamma(x*0.0811+6.12))

Strangely enough, when I say "find the expected formula", well, not exactly: it ends up with (x+1) * factorial(20) / factorial(20-x+1) / factorial(x) (I am translating here. factorial(20) is in the form of a float constant, factorial(20-x+1) is factorial(21-x).

Note that you may want to reduce a bit the maxsize parameter. It induces huge complexity in search space. And if you give it factorial function, you don't want it to search for too complex formulas...

Could you add code to show how you did it as an answer maybe?

Done (I started it before you asked :D). I commented at first because I wasn't even sure to understand the question. I discovered all this with your question. Thanks, btw, that was fun. I am not sure, since it is quite slow, and not that efficient, that I would use it professionaly, rather than good old decision trees or least squares... but you never know, so I am happy to have discovered this. So, since I started by naively add pow to the list of operators, and it worked, I figured out that it couldn't be the question. Not aware that I was just lucky to find the correct documentation.

I know at least one case when I will use that for real: next time someone bothers me with a silly so-called IQ test, what number follows 1 2 5 6 8 10 or something of that nature. Just to be able to show that there is always a "logic" and even more than one to these things.

Now that it is identified that the question was "how to add pow" (which was crystal clear from the beginning — or "why can't we use pow" —. Just, since just adding pow works on my computer, I wasn't sure that I understood the question), and also to be able to publish some code, I put my answer here.
Adding pow
Now, for a start, that adding pow is as simple as adding "^" to binary_operators:
import numpy as np
import math
from pysr import PySRRegressor

def print_pascals_triangle_row(n):
    row = []
    for k in range(n + 1):
       coefficient = math.comb(n, k)
       row.append(coefficient)
    return row

n = 20
pascals_triangle_row = print_pascals_triangle_row(n)
y = pascals_triangle_row
X = np.array(range(0, 0+len(y))).reshape(-1, 1)

model = PySRRegressor(
    maxsize=15,
    niterations=5000,  # < Increase me for better results
    binary_operators=["+", "*", "^"],
    unary_operators=[
        "log",
        "exp",
        "inv",
        "square",
        "sqrt",
        "sign",
        # ^ Custom operator (julia syntax)
    ],
    elementwise_loss="loss(prediction, target) = (prediction - target)^2",
)

res = model.fit(X, y)

(I used "pow" in my comment. But it is the exact same. I suspect that reason why it didn't work at first for you, is because you added it to unary_operator. At least, that is what commented line suggest)
It is worth noting that, doing so, it does use ^ from times to times in intermediate result. But ends up with only solution that make no usage of ^. Which is not that surprising, since,

After all, pow is already feasible using combination of exp and some multiplication.. 2^x is also exp(x*0.693147) — I don't say exp(x*log(2)) since in this case, the regressor would have used a constant

The result is really not that bad with what it does, without ^. The maximum error is 536. And 536, sure, is a lot for small y values, but that doesn't matter for the loss function that is interested only in raw difference. And 536 for the biggest value (which "leads" the loss function) is only 0,3%. For comparison, and implementation of 20!/(n!×(20-n)!) using Stirling formula has an error of 2323. And the reason why you wanted pow was to allow the regressor to use Stirling formula... well, it doesn't want to, because it found better than Stirling formula.


Changing loss function
That "-123 instead of 1 is only an error of 124, which is not so bad" maybe a good argument for the loss function, but obviously not for a human. So, to take into account that we expect error to be small in proportion of the expected value, we can change the loss function. For example
model = PySRRegressor(
    maxsize=15,
    niterations=5000,  # < Increase me for better results
    binary_operators=["+", "*"],
    unary_operators=[
        "log",
        "exp",
        "inv",
        "square",
        "sqrt",
        "sign"    
    ],
    elementwise_loss="loss(prediction, target) = (prediction/target - 1)^2",
)

This setting leads to
[1, 18, 185, 1175, 5100, 16229, 39716, 77328, 122614, 160762, 175791, 160762, 122614, 77328, 39716, 16229, 5100, 1175, 185, 18, 1]
on my computer. Compared to target
[1, 20, 190, 1140, 4845, 15504, 38760, 77520, 125970, 167960, 184756, 167960, 125970, 77520, 38760, 15504, 4845, 1140, 190, 20, 1]
So 10% error for the 2 "18 instead of 20". 5% or less for all the rest.
Reducing complexity
It is tempting to think "who can most can less" and let that parameter maxsize=15. But in reality, if maxsize is too big, that prevents exploring a lot smaller expressions. So it really help to reduce it. Besides, you can then increase the number of iteartions niterations, since it is also faster.
Adding selfpow
We can add a custom unary operator x↦xˣ
If shouldn't work (or at least not as intended) since doing so would be also to expect the regressor to rediscover Stirling formula. But it won't, since it can find better result than Stirling formula.
But for the sake of exploring how it can be done, let's do it
model = PySRRegressor(
    maxsize=10,
    niterations=5000,  # < Increase me for better results
    binary_operators=["+", "*"],
    unary_operators=[
        "log",
        "exp",
        "inv",
        "square",
        "sqrt",
        "sign",
        "selfpow(x::T) where {T} = x > 0 ? (x^x) : T(NaN)"
    ],
    extra_sympy_mappings={'selfpow': lambda x: x**x if x>0 else np.nan},
    elementwise_loss="loss(prediction, target) = (prediction - target)^2",
)

Don't be impressed by my handling of julia code: I don't know julia. Just, this was almost given to me in an error message, when I first tried selfpow(x) = x^x. It yielded an error because that function is not defined on whole ℝ (obviously it just tries some random values and catches any error raised to detect that). And that error message suggest to return NaN for invalid values. And more over gives an example of how to do so with a log example such as "log(x::T) where {T} = x > 0 ? log(x) : T(NaN)". So, I just cargo-culted the thing for my x^x.
As expected, with this setting selfpow is not used (except temporarily in intermediate results)
Adding factorial (aka cheating :D)
Likewise, we can add factorial
model = PySRRegressor(
    maxsize=10,
    niterations=50000,  # < Increase me for better results
    binary_operators=["+", "*"],
    unary_operators=[
        "log",
        "exp",
        "inv",
        "square",
        "sqrt",
        "sign",
        "fac(x) = (x>0) ? gamma(x+1) : Float32(1.0)",
    ],
    extra_sympy_mappings={'fac':lambda x: 1},
    elementwise_loss="loss(prediction, target) = (prediction - target)^2",
)

Note that the extra_sympy_mappings for fac is false. But it doesn't matter (for me), I just wanted the formula, not a sympy function. Contrarily to what the doc says, I cannot just skip the sympy mappings when I don't care. So I put anything to shut it up, since otherwise it complains. Not that it would have been hard to code a sympy equivalent. It wouuld probably took me less time that I just took to explain why I didn't :D
More importantly, note that I use not factorial but gamma.
With factorial I don't get it to use it. With gamma it does. gamma(n+1) is the same as factorial(n) when n is integer.
I did try with factorial. Which forces me to round, cast to int, then to big, then cast result back to Float32. Plus test case n<0.
But it doesn't use it. The probable cause (I am speculating here) is that this regression is obviously supposed to work on floats. And probably does some derivative at some point to optimize at least constants. But factorial, even once transformed to work on any (rounded) float, is a "stair" function. So its derivative is 0 almost everywhere (in the mathematical meaning of "almost") and not computable elsewhere.
So, I use gamma which is the real version of factorial (the complex, even, but I am interested only by real).
And with this setting (with smaller maxsize and bigger niterations as you can see) I do get the expected result
What is funny, is that I do get a 20!/(20-n)!/n! (once translated).
But that is not the best result.
The best is
(20! / (n!*753640) / (20-n)!)*753640
And in between some other strange way to say 20!/n!/(20-n)!, like sqr(sqrt(...))) and even a (20!/n!/(20-n)!)*1
All with a loss of 0, to the numerical error (some 10⁻⁵, which, since as you see, I am using your original loss, that is the "reference" are the raw values. So 10⁻⁵ is very small), except for the last one, that has a loss of exactly 0.
So, obviously, it finds the expected result, and then plays with condition number (even if I am sure that there is no explicit code in the regressor about that. I am just using the everyday abuse of supposing intentions to AI) to find some formula that reduce the numerical error.
